# selecting consecutive Id's using jquery selector - is there any short hand?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, selector

I have a 5 Div's with ID's - #C1,#C2,#C3,#C4 and #C5

Is there any way in which i can select all the [consecutive]id's at once using the selectors ?

All i can do now is :

```
 $('#C1,#C2,#C3,#C4,#C5').css({ SOME CSS });
```

Is there any other way to select when the **ID's are in consecutive order** ?

I want to select ID's from 1 to 5.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you're doing it right. `$('#C1,#C2,#C3,#C4,#C5')` is a valid selector.

Comment: Yea..but is there any other way of doing ?
some thing like $('#C[1ton]');

This is working absolutely fine but want to know is there a short hand to this ?

Comment: @Salketer :Thanks for the answer but Is there any shorthand to this ?

Something like $('#C[1 to n]') ??

Comment: Why do you need to do that anyways? Give them a class!

Comment: @Salketer: woohaa !! that never came to my mind. thanks ... will use that instead.

Comment: credit goes to @Salketer you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Omar : absolutely... credit goes to Salketer...

Comment: I actually thought you were sarcastic at first.

Comment: @Salketer: noo seriously... This really did not come to my mind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to just assign a `class` to the `<div>` elements, and use that as the selector:

```
<div id="C1" class="selectMe"> ... </div>
<div id="C2" class="selectMe"> ... </div>
<div id="C3" class="selectMe"> ... </div>
```

Then simply:

```
$('div.selectMe').css({ ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

can try like

```
$("div[id^='C']").css({ SOME CSS });
```

'^' will represents the div ids that are Started with 'C' and it selects them for your css

The above will select all the divs whose ids are starting with 'C' Or if you want to select only 5 then you can try like

```
for(var i = 1 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
     $("#C"+i).css({SOME CSS});
}
```

Comment: This is probably not a very good solution as there could be a lot of elements whose `id` starts with `C`

Comment: will also flag #content to name only one popular ID

Comment: Consider my second ans also

Answer (score 1):

Use that kind of selector

```
$('[id^=C]').filter(function(i, v){
    return !isNaN(v.id[1]);
}).css({ SOME CSS })
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/esafum/2/edit)</kbd>

Comment: "when the ID's are in consecutive order"... this will select *any* element whose ID starts with "C".

Comment: this will not help as any id like "container" will also be affected.

Comment: Worth noting that this kind of selector would be (perhaps considerably) slower to execute. If they're just trying to save on typing then this probably isn't worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish but seeing that you are trying to apply CSS rules to those elements I think that targetting multiple elements with IDs might not be the right thing to do.

You should be using classes if you are trying to target multiple elements. This also fits in a nice way to work as elements of the same kind usually share classes for CSS rules already.

So you should add a class to your elements and then change:

```
$('#C1,#C2,#C3,#C4,#C5').css({ SOME CSS });
```

by

```
$('.class').css({ SOME CSS });
```

If you really want to grab DOM elements that have consecutive ID numbers you could do this:

```
function getConsecutiveID(prefix){

    prefix = '#'+prefix;
    var stop = false;
    var selectors = [];
    var i = 1;
    while(!stop){
        if($(prefix+i).length>0){
            selectors.push(prefix+i);
        }else{
            stop =true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return $(selectors.join(','));

}
getConsecutiveID('C').css({ SOME CSS });
```

Comment: I used the class now...
But was curious to know if there is any short hand to it..

Comment: Edited to add a function to be able to grab consecutive IDs, without limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the numbers in an array, you can do this with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
$all = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(jq, i) { return jq.add("#c" + i); }, $());
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/DNKsj/)**.

This is not available natively in IE < 9 but the MDN page has a polyfill that you can use.